Delete imported photos from Mac on iPhone
I got a new iPhone. The transfer files to new iPhone feature was not working - I couldn't move the photos and files from my old iPhone to the new one.
I had the brilliant idea to move all the photos from my old iPhone to a Macbook.
After that, I synced the photos from the Macbook to the new phone.
I reseted and sold the old iPhone and the Macbook.
Now, on my new iPhone, I can't delete any photos I imported from that Macbook. They are shown in Recents and also in From My Mac.
Is there a way to be able to delete any of those imported photos on my new phone?
iCloud is disabled and there is no photo uploaded to iCloud.
My new phone is an iPhone 16 pro max with iOS 18.1

After some research it seems that the only way to do it is to:

Duplicate manually my photos (22k, it will take some time)
Sync again with another macbook or pc OR turn on icloud.

Reference: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252365117?sortBy=rank

Welcome to Ask Different. Perhaps you can transfer your comment / answer into a proper answer? It will reach more people that way, and you might earn some rep if people find it useful for themselves. Also, you can later accept your own answer.
